Font-family vs. font in matplotlib
I'd like to use the font "Montserrat" in matplotlib. In Windows "Monterrat" is shown as a "font family" with one item in the Fonts folder. When I open it in Windows' File Explorer, I see different varieties ("Montserrat Black", "Montserrat SemiBold", ...) shown as fonts in this font family.
In matplotlib, "Montserrat" is available as a font-family but there doesn't seem to be a way to select a font in that font-family. The "fontweight" attribute has no effect whatsoever on how the output looks and doesn't accept the different font names as values.
How can I use the different font varieties in matplotlib?

Could it be you installed the variable font version (one font file for multiple weights)? If so matplotlib may not support it (as many other applications still missing VF support). You can download the complete Montserrat font family on google fonts and install the static versions (you see a static folder when unpacking the zip)
